# Yii2 Filter data with multiple relation

Tags: sorting, yii, yii2, filtering, yii2-advanced-app

I am working on and listing page of boats where boats are of two types

- Shared.
- Private.

**If shared boats are available**

i have to check

- if they provide half-day (1/2) trip then price will be shown of half day.
- if half-day is not available then check if three fourths(3/4) of a day and price will be three forth of a day.
- Else  check for full day and take price of full day.

**If shared boat is not available**

- Check for private boat available.
- Then apply the same scenario given above for the private boats.

For these pricing i used conditions but in filtering of high-to-low/low-to-high price filtering i can't get any idea how to apply conditions. Can someone help me to solve these.

Models :

- `Boatinformation(Main)`.
- `Boatsharedfishingtrip(shared pricing)`
- `Boatfishingcharter(Private Pricing)`

Model Relations :

```
public function getBoatfishingcharter() {
    return $this->hasOne(Boatfishingcharter::className(), ['boat_id' => 'boat_id']);
}

public function getBoatsharedtrip() {
    return $this->hasOne(Boatsharedfishingtrip::className(), ['boat_id' => 'boat_id']);
}

if($model->boatsharedtrip->shared_fishing_charters == '1') {
    if($model->boatsharedtrip->one_two_day_4hrs == 1) {
        $shared_price = $model->boatsharedtrip->one_two_day_rate_per_angler;
    } else if($model->boatsharedtrip->three_four_day_6hrs == 1) {
        $shared_price = $model->boatsharedtrip->three_four_day_rate_per_angler;
    } else if($model->boatsharedtrip->full_day_8hrs == 1) {
        $shared_price = $model->boatsharedtrip->full_day_rate_per_angler;
    }
} else if($model->boatfishingcharter->private_fishing_charters == 1) {

    if($model->boatfishingcharter->one_two_day_4hrs == 1) {
        $private_price = $model->boatfishingcharter->one_two_day_rate;
    } else if($model->boatfishingcharter->three_four_day_6hrs == 1) {
        $private_price = $model->boatfishingcharter->three_four_day_rate;
    } else if($model->boatfishingcharter->full_day_8hrs == 1) {
        $private_price = $model->boatfishingcharter->full_day_rate;
    }
}
```

For filter i am currently using :

```
if($_GET['orderby'] == 'price_desc') {
    $query->orderBy(['one_two_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'one_two_day_rate' => SORT_DESC, 'three_four_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'three_four_day_rate' => SORT_DESC, 'full_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'full_day_rate' => SORT_DESC]);
} elseif($_GET['orderby'] == 'price_asc') {
    $query->orderBy(['one_two_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'one_two_day_rate' => SORT_ASC, 'three_four_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'three_four_day_rate' => SORT_ASC, 'full_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'full_day_rate' => SORT_ASC]);
}


$query = Boatinformation::find();
        $query->leftJoin('boatsharedfishingtrip', '`boatsharedfishingtrip`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->leftJoin('rating_review', '`rating_review`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->leftJoin('boatotherservice', '`boatotherservice`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->leftJoin('boatfishingequipment', '`boatfishingequipment`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->join('INNER JOIN','boatcompanyinformation', '`boatcompanyinformation`.`id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->leftJoin('boatfishingcharter', '`boatfishingcharter`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
              ->where(['boat_publish' => 1])->all();
```

**Edit**

This is how i am displaying the boats in the listing

[image]

Comment: when you say you are working on the listing page are you using the `GridView` to display the listing?

Comment: no i am working on front side and not using grid view

Comment: you should add the view you are working on and why not `GridView` if the layout of the listing is going to be similar to `GridView` it can reduce alot of effort for the HTML layout fixes

Comment: i added image of by listing . i have many other functionlity which is working. i can't use grid view

Comment: add your view code. How you render list, how you build array and Query

Comment: added query above and rendering pricing by model relations as mention above for pricing

Comment: the image you provided above you can achieve the same layout of cards using [`ListView`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-widgets-listview) easily along with pagination. here is the [Guide Article](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/output-data-widgets) but you need to add you view file

Comment: i can use these layout but my question is regarding filter how can i achieve filter as  i have relational tables for pricing.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam can you help me for sorting price wise list ? is any yii2 specific model relations case conditions which i can use ?

Comment: You were sorting query before calculation that won't work. One solution is you build array from query then apply filter on calculated field probably using [usort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php)

Comment: @InsaneSkull I already tried these solution but after these i can't apply pagination.  as i fetched all data for sorting. i lost pagination.

Comment: i need pagination also. as these is many listing records.

Comment: I guess still possible to retain pagination, you are probably using `LinkPager`?

Comment: Yes i am using LinkPager. but problem is that first apply pagination and then i apply filters. then both will work but it first paginate records and then applying filters to every page. suppose if in first page pricing will start from $70 sorting works then in second page if price is $50. it displayed in second page. which is wrong.

Comment: how are you filtering the results aer you using search model or you are using some custom function ,please add the complete function rather than partial code chunks, they dont help in understanding the complete workflow

Comment: I guess your order by should be inside query not above query. It may work to sort all fields. Here, order by doesn't apply on query anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Do I correctly understand that relation type between tables is "one-to-one"? 
I mean Boatinformation, Boatsharedfishingtrip and Boatfishingcharter?

Try this.

```
// Main query
$query = Boatinformation::find()
    ->leftJoin('boatsharedfishingtrip', '`boatsharedfishingtrip`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->leftJoin('rating_review', '`rating_review`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->leftJoin('boatotherservice', '`boatotherservice`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->leftJoin('boatfishingequipment', '`boatfishingequipment`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->join('INNER JOIN', 'boatcompanyinformation', '`boatcompanyinformation`.`id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->leftJoin('boatfishingcharter', '`boatfishingcharter`.`boat_id` = `boatinformation`.`boat_id`')
    ->where(['boat_publish' => 1]);


// Sort
$orderBy = Yii::$app->request->get('orderby');

switch ($orderBy) {
    case 'price_desc':
        $query->orderBy(['one_two_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'one_two_day_rate' => SORT_DESC, 'three_four_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'three_four_day_rate' => SORT_DESC, 'full_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_DESC, 'full_day_rate' => SORT_DESC]);
        break;

    case 'price_asc':
        $query->orderBy(['one_two_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'one_two_day_rate' => SORT_ASC, 'three_four_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'three_four_day_rate' => SORT_ASC, 'full_day_rate_per_angler' => SORT_ASC, 'full_day_rate' => SORT_ASC]);
        break;
}


// Execute
// var_dump( $query->createCommand()->getRawSql() );  // Uncomment to debug built SQL

$query->all();
```

Are you using Yii2 debug toolbar? If so, copy-paste here built SQL. 
If no, uncomment `getRawSql` line. It may help to figure out why it does not work for you.

Comment: I read your question. But firstly, I am trying to guess how you tried to solve this problem. Because your code is incorrect and it won't work in any case.

Comment: @JankiRathod If I correctly understood your problem, you are trying to calculate "summary price" using PHP. This approach does allow to filter using MySQL. There are two ways for this case: 1) you may build SQL expression for this price, and use it for filtering and sorting. 2) you may load all necessary records to PHP, calculate all prices, prepare ArrayDataProvider, and display it with Pager. Bot ways work fine with filtering, pagination and sorting, but second way requires more memory and CPU time.